# How to fix KeyError - exception?

Tags: pandas, exception, keyerror

I don't understand why there is an issue with the key since upon a print it exists, can someone help please?

```
% python3 auto_fill_doc_from_excel.py 
['first;last;title']
```

Here are details on the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3790, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "index.pyx", line 152, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "index.pyx", line 181, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7080, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7088, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'first'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ninatyminska/Documents/auto_fill_doc_from_excel.py", line 15, in <module>
    context = {'first_name': row['first'],
                             ~~~^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 1040, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 1156, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3797, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'first'
```

Except of print I didn't try anything else.

Here is the code:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

doc = DocxTemplate("Template_Attendence_Certificate.docx")

today_date = datetime.today().strftime("%d %b, %Y")

my_context = {'today_date': today_date}

df = pd.read_csv('poster_presentation.csv')
#print(df.columns.tolist())

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    context = {'first_name': row['first'],
                      'last_name': row['last'],
               'poster_title': row['title']}
    context.update(my_context)

    doc.render(context)
    doc.save(f"Attendence_Certificate_{index}.docx")
```

Comment: Check for trailing spaces or capitalization?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it seems that the issue is not related to either of those.

Comment: What is the exact output of `df.columns`?

Comment: I don't know how to check for that.

Comment: `print(df.columns)`?

Comment: @BigBen - here is what I got: Index(['first;last;title'], dtype='object')

Comment: That's one column. Therefore you need `df = pd.read_csv('poster_presentation.csv', sep=';')`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [KeyError while reading a CSV file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70464125/keyerror-while-reading-a-csv-file-in-python)

Comment: @BigBen Thanks that worked. Do you know how could I modify the code so that the name of newly generated document was Attendance_Certficate_{first_name}_{last_name}.docx instead of  Attendence_Certificate_{index}.docx ?

Comment: You have a reference to the first name and last name already: `row['first']` and `row['last']`. So add those into the filename? Or use `context['first_name']` and `context['last_name']`.

Comment: Ok, but how I'm a novice to coding (python)?